# attempted to assign to readonly property - animated.spring

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to make a simple animation for a card to slide up. I have designed the card, and I found an example online for how to use the Animate.spring function. I followed that but it throws the error: attempted to assign to readonly property.

I can only assume that it is referring to the state, but I specifically changed the state from read only. I have tried searching online for a solution and every stack or git solution I find says to make sure youre using animated.values or animated.views. I am using both and it is still throwing this error. I tried restarting the app and vscode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first image is my call to Animated spring and the second is my render

Comment: please add your code here